# Is it okay to perform ghusul in the bathroom?

Tags: ritual

We know that Ghusal is mandatory for every person who has done sexual intercourse, orgasmic discharges *"semen"* etc...

There is one problem with me. In my home, bath room and toilet room are together so is it okay to perform Ghusal in their?

Comment: why do you think it is haram.

Comment: @Mhmd I have the same question. If there is toilet and bathroom at the same place, then impurity of toilet may come intact to us when water falls from height.

Also, I want to ask that, how is it to us same Mug [the small pot to take water] for toilet and bath?

Comment: @user you seem to have misunderstood the concept of impurity. Unless you are clearly seeing the source of impurity, there is nothing impure about it. The toilet -just being a place for it- doesn't make it impure.

Comment: @Mhmd Do you want to state that if I throw water on impurity then the place will be pure. If we know that it is toilet and was not clean a minute ago.

Comment: In my view after a proper toilet mop, the place can be said pure.
And the statement you made is for some general place where you have to offer prayer and if you don't see or feel any impurity then that place is allowed to offer prayer.

Comment: @user there is a big difference between impurity and cleanliness. I'm only saying that, the toilet can be considered pure unless you are clearly seeing the source of impurity. (which is very unlikely)

Comment: @Mhmd I would like to have some reference for the above comment, if any. thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16241/discussion-between-mhmd-and-user263210).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Nothing is Haram unless it's stated that it is, or is derived from or drives something that is Haram.

Comment: Do you know any Ayah or Hadith related to it?

Comment: @Murtaza A general Hadith would apply here: "Halal is clear, and Haram is clear, and there are interlocking things in between that a lot of people don't know ". And a question has been asked in the Fatwa center of Islam web here: http://fatwa.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=134879 but it's in Arabic. They provided 3 quotes from scholars as interpretations, but as I said, you can't find a Hadith or Ayah about bathroom etiquette when there wasn't any back then, but rather scholars compare this to other "clear Halal" or "clear Haram" and amend this to that. It's a

Comment: @Murtaza It's a branch in Fiqh (science of understanding of Islam) called Al-Que'ias "القياس" or the "comparison" in English

Comment: @Murtaza I meant append not amend.

Comment: @Murtaza Sorry the link in Fatwa Center is for something else. But the rest on my comments are correct.